# angular custom pipe that is async

Tags: angular

I am using angular (7+) and have the following custom pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'enumtostring'
})
export class EnumtostringPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private translateEnumService: TranslateenumService) { }

  transform(value: any, type$?: any): any {
    if(value && type$) {
        // this returns an observable of type Observable<string>
        return this.translateEnumService.translateEnumObservable(type$, value);
    }
    return value;    
  }

}
```

To use this pipe, I always have to use the keyword *async* too:

```
{{ KalkulationsTyp.Monat | enumtostring : KalkulationsTyp | async }}
```

How can I rewrite my pipe so that I can omit the async pipe while using it? Inherit from async pipe? How do I do that?

Comment: In my opinion using the chained async pipe is totally valid and the way to go. Why you want to get rid of that?

Comment: Valid point. The pipe's client must not forget the async pipe and it seems like a redundancy.